# CORS error when requesting Data with a JSON object in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, json, aws-lambda, cors

I am working on a serverless application using AWS Lambda, a MYSQL database and API Gateway as Backend.
I have several functions already working which use GET or POST methods to query the database. However, now I need to perform a query using data that the user selects in the web app. It is just a simple query, however, I am running with the following problem: when I send the query as a simple string, the API works well, although the query gives error (because I didn't send in the JSON format that Lambda works with). However, when I try to send a JSON object, the API gives the following error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is my javascript code: `

```
var queryJSON = '{ "filter": "' + query + '"}';
function get_statistics() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "url...",
        type: "get",
        data: queryJSON,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
}`
```

Probably I am doing some mistake, but I don't manage to figure it out, thanks :)

Comment: I don’t know if it applies to your case, but I get this error whenever I try to send or get data via HTTP instead of HTTPS. Of course, I mean when the CORS policy itself doesn’t block requests from other domains (even working locally from `localhost`).

Comment: I am sending to a HTTPS API, still the CORS is only giving problems if I send JSON string in the data field.

Comment: In the case where you send a JSON object and you get that CORS error, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: yes, it is a 400 error in the response header

Answer (score 0):

you can set up the required headers by using API Gateway method response and integration response settings. API Gateway will create an OPTIONS method and attempt to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to your existing method integration responses. **This doesn’t always work and sometimes you need to manually modify the integration response to properly enable CORS**.

The following is an example of a Lambda function that is configured to return the required CORS headers:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "x-custom-header" : "custom header value",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: {}
    }; 
    context.succeed(response)
}
```

hope it would fix your problem, please make sure your request and response headers are same.